# Pattern matches Sin but not Exp?

Tags: pattern-matching

I want to write a pattern that matches unary functions applied to a certain head named `dual`, used in replacement rules like this:

```
f_[dual[a_, A_]] :> unimportant replacement
```

The pattern matches `Sin`

```
Cases[{Sin[dual[x, X]]},f_[dual[a_, A_]]]
```

> ```
> {Sin[dual[x, X]]}
> ```

and an arbitrary head, say `exp`

```
Cases[{exp[dual[a, A]]}, f_[dual[a_, A_]]]
```

> ```
> {exp[dual[a, A]]}
> ```

but not real `Exp`

```
Cases[{Exp[dual[a, A]]}, f_[dual[a_, A_]]]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Any ideas why not?

**EDIT**

I found out that `Exp` is `ReadProtected`, but `Sin` is not. I don't quite see how that accounts for the difference in pattern-matching, however.

Comment: Evaluate `Exp[dual[a, A]]` on it's own to see (it turns into `E^dual[a, A]`).

Comment: Yup, that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compare

```
FullForm[Sin[t]]
```

and

```
FullForm[Exp[t]]
```

you will see that that `Exp` is automatically simplified to

```
Power[E, t]
```